# Can ellipsoid aircraft reach high speeds

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft

Imagining an ellipsoid aircraft/spacecraft something like [image: this]

Could something like this reach high speeds? Assuming those nacelles hold some high tech ramjets or something equally powerful. I noticed that from the front you can't see the nacelles, how would the air flow into them? Or would it not flow into them. Would the whole thing have to rotate to experience the Coriolis effect?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is suited more to [worldbuilding.se] or [aviation.se].  It does not seem to be about a physics concept and it more about the design of a hypothetical aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

It would reach a higher speed if it had a more streamlined design, thus reducing air resistance.